# Construct cocyle from Leray-Serre spectral sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, sheaf-cohomology, spectral-sequences

Let $F \xrightarrow{f} E \rightarrow B$ be a fiber bundle and $L$ is the locally constant sheaf on $E$. $B$ is **NOT** simply connected.

We can apply Leray-Serre spectral sequence to compute the local cohomology of $E$, and assume that $E_2$ page of the spectral sequence converged.

**My question** is that how I can read the information of cocycles in $H^{p+q}(E;L)$ from cocycles in $H^p(B;R^{q}f_*L)$?

More explicitly, what is the explicit map from $H^p(B;R^{q}f_*L)$ in the language of deRham cohomology.